# Using Tomcat for authentication | NGINX ERROR 301 MOVED

Tags: authentication, nginx, http-status-code-301

I have a test NGINX workload which I'm restricting to (any) internal corporate users. Users authenticate via our organization's internal IAM platform.  I'm using a Tomcat webapp for authenticating users and I'm attempting to configure Nginx with auth_request to control the access. I'm not concerned with authorization at this point.

from: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/

> NGINX makes an HTTP subrequest to an external server where the subrequest is verified. If the subrequest returns a 2xx response code, the access is allowed, if it returns 401 or 403, the access is denied.

My Tomcat app appears to be working properly. I can manually browse to the app (/auth), complete authentication, and receive a 200 response code.

Something is wrong with my NGINX configuration. When I browse to the protected workload (/test), I am prompted for authentication. Upon successful authentication, my web browser returns an "Unable to connect" (the site can't be reached) error. If I run a packet capture, I can see the web server returning an error 301 resource moved (this is also observed in the NGINX access logs).

I'm not sure why NGINX is not serving up the workload. The error and access logs are not very helpful. Is there anything else that I can troubleshoot? The NGINX server is running on RHEL7. This is a test workload. I have autoindex configured in NGINX, so I believe the correct behavior is to serve up a directory structure (I placed a few test files in /data/www/test/).  Once I figure this out, I'll need to move the auth mechanism into production, and start restricting real workloads.

I could be wrong, but I think this is a syntax issue..? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

nginx.conf

```
# iFor more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
# include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
#    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  localhost;
#        root          /data/www;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#       include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location /test {
           root /data/www;
           autoindex on; 
       auth_request  /auth/;
       auth_request_set  $auth_status   $upstream_status;
       }


        location = /auth/ {
            internal;
            proxy_pass              http://0.0.0.0:8080;
            proxy_pass_request_body off;
            proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
            proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        }



        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

welp, this was my mistake...

I'm running my workload in virtualbox on my local machine, and I had a typo in my NAT config.

how embarrassing

On a positive note, a colleague helped me by suggesting that I comment out auth-request in NGINX to test NGINX without the auth piece. That was very helpful in figuring out the issue.